# Create External content type using Powershell

Tags: 2010, external-content-type

How would one go about creating an external content type using powershell?

Is it at all possible?

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/139899/create-an-external-content-type-with-powershell It's for 2013, but it should be no different for 2010. I don't think there is a better approach to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is to Create ECT using SharePoint Designer (It is much easier).

Then export model file and use PowerShell to import it into other environments.

Comment: You gave a good answer to it previously, maybe add a link to it? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/139905/35095

Comment: @Dolgsthrasir yes I remember already answering this. Tx for sharing link :)